# Run Python script via CMD

Tags: python

I have the following file: `up.py`

in this file:

```
def main(a_param, b_param, c_param):
    // Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

I want to run this python file via the CMD, so I write this line:

```
python up.py False True False
```

But I get the next error:

```
TypeError: main() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call your `main` function without arguments event though it requires 3 (`a_param`, `b_param` and `c_param`).

The command line parameters are stored in `sys.argv`. To call the `main` function with the first 3 command line parameters, you could this:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv[1:4])
```

To clarify, `*` unpacks the argument list so `main(*sys.argv[1:4])` is equivalent to `main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with CMD. Your `main` function expects three arguments, but you aren't passing any; you call it directly from your `if __name__ == '__main__'` block with just `main()`.

Either get the arguments (eg from `sys.argv`) within that block and pass them to main, or remove the arguments from the function signature and get them within main.

Answer (score -2):

This code works for me

```
def main(a_param, b_param, c_param):
    # Code
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        exit(main())
```

then:

`$ python up.py False True False`